# SQL Server suspended

Tags: sql-server, c#-4.0

I have two applications that do something to the same SQL Server table. One application uses C# `SqlBulkCopy` to import about two hundred thousand records into the SQL Server table, and the other application queries data from the same SQL Server table.

I find this message - please check the screenshot. The table has one hundred million rows. How can I fix it?

[image: Please check this picture]

Comment: If your application #1 is bulk-loading 200'000 rows into the table, then that table will be **exclusively locked** for the duration of the loading process - therefore, your application #2 won't be able to query that table, **until the loading process is done.**

Comment: So I can't do nothing?  I think SqlBulkCopy  wait_time = 4314076 millisecond is to slow.  Is it SqlBulkCopy  problem?

Answer (score 1):

If any transaction is modifying a table and affecting *more than 5000 rows*, then SQL Server will *escalate* the locking from row-level locking to an exclusive table lock.

So if your application #1 is bulk-loading 200'000 rows into the table, then that table will be exclusively locked for the duration of the loading process.

Therefore, your application #2 - or any other client - won't be able to query that table, until the loading process is done.

This is **normal, documented, expected behavior** on the part of SQL Server.

Either make sure you load your data in batches of less than 5000 rows at a time during business hours, or then do the bulk-loading after hours, when no one is being negatively impacted by an exclusive table lock.

Comment: Would a `NOLOCK` hint be helpful in this case?

Comment: @NisargShah: I don't think so, since the whole table is exclusively locked